# partial match using table entries

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table with the following values:

Table name - `title`

```
id   val
1    director
1    developer
1    executive
```

I have another table - `table2`

```
id  user   title_val
1   abc    adirector
2   abc1   bdeveloperc
3   abc2   aexecutive
```

I want to create a sql query using the above table - table2 to do partial matching like:

```
select * 
from table2 
where title_val like '%director%' 
   OR title like '%developer%' 
   OR title like '%executive%';
```

I know I can do - `select * from table2 where title in (select val from title)`, but it would be exact match and NOT partial match.

I want to use the table entries from title. I have 1000s of titles. Is there any SQL query which can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggregate all the titles into an array and then use LIKE with the ANY operator:

```
select *
from table2
where title_val like any( array(select concat('%', val, '%') from title) )
```

As you are not using Postgres, you can use a sub-query instead

```
select *
from table2 t2
where exists (select *
              from title tt
              where t2.title_val like concat('%', tt.val, '%') )
```

Comment: Is there alternative to ANY? I am also using Redshift and it does not work there.

Comment: @dang: that's why you should not tag Redshift questions with Postgres. They are not the same. See my edit

Comment: Makes sense. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for your table

```
select * from title where val like '%director%' OR val like '%developer%' or val like '%executive%';
```

Comment: This is static way of doing it. I want to use the table entries from title. I have 1000s of titles. Want to use a query which can do it for me.

Comment: Please Re-phrase your question with this information.

Comment: Added more info to the question.